# Unity 5.4.2 - Scale and position instantiated UI elements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've been working on a project for a class I'm in and have run into a pickle that I can't seem to resolve. I have asked the instructor and he was confused as I was.

Right now I've just been trying to set up a simple UI for displaying a list of buttons to select a level to load. At runtime the code simply creates the appropriate buttons and such, and places them within a *scrollview's* content object. Simple enough, right? Well, [as you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5EPR.png) the position and right are completely wrong, by *800 units*.

The **Canvas is set to a Screen Space - Overlay** and the **Canvas Scaler is set to scale with screen size**, which I'm guessing is the problem. I already had the problem of the position and scale being even more off (depending on the screen size), but "fixed" this by manually setting the transform's position and localscale.

I have however had no luck finding a solution to this, with all my googling, so I'd be very appreciative if someone could help me with this and explain to me what the problem is.

Here is the code that it executes for each of the levels. It's of course messy because I've been trying about as much as I could to figure out what the problem is.

```
        Level thisLevel = levelManager.levelList [i];
        GameObject levelButton = (GameObject)Instantiate (menuManager.levelButtonContainerObject);

        levelButton.transform.SetParent (menuManager.mainMenuLevelContainer.transform, false);
        levelButton.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
        levelButton.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        levelButton.transform.localScale = Vector2.one;

        RectTransform levelButtonRect = levelButton.GetComponent<RectTransform> ();
//          levelButtonRect.position = ApplyCanvasScale (new Vector3 (0f, -50 + (-100 * i), 0f));
        levelButtonRect.position = new Vector3(0f, -50 + (-100 * i), 0f);
//          levelButtonRect.position = Vector3.zero;
        levelButtonRect.sizeDelta = new Vector2 (0f, 100f);
        Debug.Log ("Position " + levelButtonRect.position + ", Scale " + levelButtonRect.sizeDelta);
```

Comment: I may have answered prematurely. Are the buttons getting parented to a VerticalLayoutGroup?

Comment: how do you anchor the ui object? is it center or stretch-filled or...?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these where you're setting position and scale:

```
levelButton.transform.offsetMin = Vector2.zero
levelButton.transform.offsetMax = Vector2.zero
```